# jQuery: Multiply a number with 7.5

Tags: javascript, jquery, calculator, bigcartel

I'm about to design a webshop, build upon the Big Cartel webshop system. The nearest currency they use is Euro, but I want Danish Kroner (DKK), which is 7.5 of Euro.

How can I multiply the number within a div.price?

I've found "jQuery Calculate"-plugin, but I can't figure out how it works.

Plugin site: http://www.pengoworks.com/workshop/jquery/calculation/calculation.plugin.htm

Thank you in advance...

Comment: (Insert mandatory reference to [jQuery basic arithmetic plugin](http://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif) here :)

Comment: Could you explain why you can't just use a combination of jQuery to get the current value in div.price and then just use good old javascript to multiply it by 7.5, then using jQuery to update the div?

Comment: Do you actually need to convert between currencies? Is it simply a matter of changing the symbol from Euro to DKK?

Comment: I don't understand. will you be converting your DKK prices to euro, sticking them as euro, reading them back out as euro, and then convering to DKK client side? Just bung them in as DKK values, who cares what a DB field is named?

Comment: Hi guys. I'm new to Javascript and doesn't know very much about it. However I use jQuery alot, and always search for plugins or snippets by searching "jquery ..."... @Mark: How would the script look like then? Or where can I find something like this? @El Ronnoco: The Danish currency is 7,5 times greater than Euro. That mean, that if I just change the symbol, the products would be 7,5 times cheaper than they really are. The customers would love it I bet. But not my client.. ;-)

Comment: Richard: Bigcartel.com doesn't support DKK. Only Euro.

Comment: I presume that what he actually needs is to extract a `1000.5` float from a `1.000,50` string. Whatever, the linked plugin seems to have an excellent documentation so it may help if you told us what you got so far and where you're stuck.

Comment: I think Javascript can only multiply up to about 6, for numbers bigger than 6 you need to use JQuery

Comment: You probably know this, but note: The Euro:DKK rate is 7.46038, not 7.5 and doesn't seem to be entirely fixed? Not sure I understand how this works. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danish_krone

Comment: I agree, jQuery is really the best, it solves all kinds of browser problems and is good, as well.

Comment: @Pekka: Both the Euro, and the Danish Krone is fixed. I just wrote 7.5.

Comment: @Kenneth but it does not seem entirely fixed, see: http://www.finanzen.net/devisen/euro-daenische_krone-kurs I'm confused. Anyway, for purposes of calculating a customer price, a fixed rate is probably good enough

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('div.price').text(function(i,v) {
    return Math.round(parseInt(v * 100, 10) * 7.5) / 100;
});
```

***Live demo:*** http://jsfiddle.net/tbL5r/

Answer (score 2):

```
$("div.price").each(function(){
 $(this).text(parseFloat($(this).text()) * 7.5);
});
```

But you really shouldn't be doing that with javascript.

Comment: This will lead to prices like `20.725` though, won't it? It will need some decimal formatting...

Comment: Why not? For a simple currency conversion sending a request to the server would be pretty much overkill. However, if it's about changing a shop-wide setting.. then a reload is absolutely fine and appropriate.

Comment: @Pekka, that wasn't part of the question ;)

Comment: Agreed about not wanting to do it with JS.  But if you must, you probably want to multiply everything by 100 first and then divide by 100 at the end.  This will avoid any floating point issues.

Comment: I can't change anything in the webshop, as it's a hosted solution. I can however add my own css and javascript, so there for I thought it would be a good solution.

Comment: Ivo - I believe that JS stores all numbers as floating point hence my suggestion to multiply & divide by 100.

Comment: Best practice is not to ever use floats to store monetary values. Floats are systematic approximations of float operations, the values stored are the parameters for these operations. Not all systems even resolve a float value to the same representation, so it is possible to get incorrect representation without even performing a single operation!

Comment: Agreed, you shouldn't use floats for any internal calculations, but given that JS doesn't have a more suitable type, and this is just a hack for display purposes, this is the least of Kenneth's worries.

Comment: True enough. As you said, this shouldn't be done on the client anyway. Suppose the user has JS turned off?

Comment: If the client has JS turned off, they will just see the Euro. They will be charged Euro as well. The DKK prices is just for display, to help users quickly see what it cost.